# Apache Kafka: Could Not Find the Main Class

Tags: classnotfoundexception, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I am trying to go through the basic quickstart for setting up kafka (found here: http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html). I have run the sbt update and package commands. Unfortunately, when I then run:

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

I see the error, "Could not find the main class ...QuorumPeerMain"

Similarly, when I run:

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

I see the error, "Could not find the main class ... kafka.Kafka"

Has anyone seen similar problems? I have checked and it looks like the zookeeper jar and kafka jar are in the classpath. If it helps, I have version 7.1 and am running on windows. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is most certainly a classpath problem and I would suggest to re-check that again.

Comment: I ended up using version 8.0, and the start up worked for that. Thanks for the suggestion,though!